# spring freemarker add attribute inside handlerinterceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, freemarker

I want to pass an object I have stored in the Session to each Template. I am using Spring Boot and FreeMarker. Saving the object to the scoped Component and accessing it inside the HandlerInterceptor implementation works fine. 
To expose attributes to the Template I use ModelAndView#addObject(name, obj), which works also using simple values like Strings, or Ints. But like I have mentioned in the top, I can't access fields / methods in the Template from objects I have exposed using this way.

My HandlerInterceptor implementation:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor( onConstructor = @__( @Inject ) )
public class SessionInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    private final UserComponent userComponent;

    @Override
    public void postHandle( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView ) {
        modelAndView.addObject( "test", 1234 );
        modelAndView.addObject( "testobject", this.userComponent.getTestObject() );
    }
}
```

Test Object:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class TestObject {
    private int number;
    private String name;
}
```

My ftl File:

```
<h1>${test}</h1>
<h1>${testobject}</h1>
```

Result:

```
1.234
TestObject(number=12, name=xy)
```

Changed ftl File:

```
<h1>${testobject.name}</h1>
```

New Result:

```
FreeMarker template error (DEBUG mode; use RETHROW in production!): The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> testobject.name [in template "index.ftl" at line 1, column 7] ---- Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it. ---- Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)?? ---- ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: ${testobject.name} [in template "index.ftl" at line 12, column 5] ---- Java stack trace (for programmers): ---- freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...] at freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:134) at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToTextualCommon(EvalUtil.java:467) at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToStringOrMarkup(EvalUtil.java:389) at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToStringOrMarkup(EvalUtil.java:358) at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.calculateInterpolatedStringOrMarkup(DollarVariable.java:100) at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:63) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:330) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:336) at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:309) at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:384) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.processTemplate(FreeMarkerView.java:396) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.doRender(FreeMarkerView.java:309) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.renderMergedTemplateModel(FreeMarkerView.java:257) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractTemplateView.java:165) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:314) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem must be that the `TestObject` class itself is not public. That's required by the JavaBeans Specification, even if the getter methods are already public.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.